# Add hover effect on dynamically created button in WPF c#

Tags: c#, wpf, button

I am still new to Windows App development.

I'm trying to create a button dynamically, and I don't know how to remove the default background color on hover and add a custom background color instead.

In my `XAML` file, I can easily do that like this:

```
<Button
    Margin="20"
    Height="40"
    FontSize="17"
    Foreground="White"
    x:Name="LoginButton"
    Content="LOGIN"
    Cursor="Hand">
    <Button.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <Border Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                            <ContentPresenter Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Border>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green"/>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Button.Style>
</Button>
```

But it seem difficult to achieve this with `c#`. Here's my code:

```
var style = new Style
{
    TargetType = typeof(Border),
    Setters = { new Setter { Property = Border.CornerRadiusProperty, Value = new CornerRadius(4) } }
};
Button button = new Button();
button.Content = "Click Here";
button.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colour.red);
button.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colour.white);
button.Resources.Add(style.TargetType, style);
```

Please I need help on how to add a custom background color when I hover on the button

Answer (score 0):

You have to create an entire style and then apply changes in the section that you want.

Go to de XAML design, right click to the control and Edit Template -> Edit as copy.

Then it will generates a style code and you will can change each property.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

When you find yourself creating controls and adding them to the UI in C# then you are very likely doing something wrong or having a bad design. In WPF you usually use a `DataTemplate` to create a control or visual content dynamically.
[Microsoft learn: Data Templating Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/data-templating-overview?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8).
You have not provided enough information to allow you to help you to improve your code.

Not sure what `Colour` is but WPF already has the `Colors` type (e.g. `Colors.Red`).
Or to get default-colored brushes use the `Brushes` type that returns a frozen `SolidColorBrush` instance (e.g., `Brushes.Red`).

You can fix your current code as follows (I generally don't recommend it unless you haven't considered to use `DataTemplate` first):

Define the `Style` in *App.xaml* (in general, avoid building styles and templates in C# and if you have to, the recommended way is to deserialize a XAML string using the `XamlReader`).
Next, define an attached property that allows you to define an individual mouse-over color on the element (you don't need this step if you want all your elements to share the same mouse-over color. In this case you can simply define the static color in the `ControlTemplate`. Then create the element in C# and retrieve the `Style` from the application's resource dictionary and assign it to the element:

**App.xaml**

```xml
<Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
  <Setter Property="Background" Value="DarkGreen"/>
  <Setter Property="Template">
    <Setter.Value>
      <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
        <Border x:Name="Border" 
                Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"        
                BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}">
          <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        </Border>

        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>

          <!-- 
               The trigger will get the Brush of the attached MouseOverBrush property 
               to set the mouse over Background 
          -->
          <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter TargetName="Border" 
                    Property="Background" 
                    Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=(local:FrameworkElementHelper.MouseOverBrush)}"/>
          </Trigger>
        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
      </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
  </Setter>
</Style>
```

**FramwworkElementHelper.cs**
Helper class to define the attached property.
Alternatively, this property can be defined on any existing custom `DependencyObject`.

```cs
public class FrameworkElementHelper : DependencyObject
{
  public static Brush GetMouseOverBrush(DependencyObject attachingElement)
    => (Brush)attachingElement.GetValue(MouseOverBrushProperty);

  public static void SetMouseOverBrush(DependencyObject attachingElement, Brush value)
    => attachingElement.SetValue(MouseOverBrushProperty, value);

  public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseOverBrushProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
    "MouseOverBrush",
    typeof(Brush),
    typeof(FrameworkElementHelper),
    new PropertyMetadata(default(Brush), OnMouseOverBrushChanged));

  private static void OnMouseOverBrushChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    if (e.NewValue is Brush newBrush && newBrush.CanFreeze)
    {
      newBrush.Freeze();
    }
  }
}
```

### Usage Example

**C#**

```cs
Brush backgroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
backgroundBrush.Freeze();
Brush foregroundBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.White);
foregroundBrush.Freeze();

// Or better use the Brushes type to get a default colored SolidColorBrush 
// that is also already frozen
Brush backgroundBrush = Brushes.Red;
Brush foregroundBrush = Brushes.White;

Button button = new Button()
{
  Content = "Click Here",
  Background = backgroundBrush,
  Foreground = foregroundBrush
};

Brush mouseOverBrush = Brushes.Green;

// Set the elements mouse-over color by setting the attached property.
FrameworkElementHelper.SetMouseOverBrush(button, mouseOverBrush);
```

**XAML**

```xml
<Button Content="Click Here"
        Background="Red"
        Foreground="White"
        FrameworkElementHelper.MouseOverBrush="Green" />
```